# How would I write this code without using the && or the || operator?

Tags: java, formatting, operators

```java
public static double calculateMinPayment(double newBalance) {
    double x;
    if (newBalance < 0.00) {
        return 0.00;
    } else if (newBalance > 0.00 && newBalance <= 49.99) {
        x = newBalance;
    } else if (newBalance >= 50.00 && newBalance <= 300) {
        x = 50.00;
    } else {
        x = newBalance * 0.2;
    }
    return x;     
}
```

I'm not able to use the operators && or ||, how would I be able to format this same code without those operators?

Answer (score 2):

Since your conditions are in increasing size and with no gaps you don't need any AND conditions and the comparison can be made quite straight forward.

```
public static double calculateMinPayment(double newBalance) {
  double x;

  if (newBalance < 0.0) {
    return 0.0;
  } else if (newBalance < 50.0) {
    return newBalance;
  } else if (newBalance <= 300.0) {
    return 50.0;
  } else {
    return newBalance * 0.2;
  }
}
```

A small variation is to skip all the `else` since we are using `return`

```
if (newBalance < 0.0) {
  return 0.0;
} 
if (newBalance < 50.0) {
  return newBalance;
} 
if (newBalance <= 300.0) {
  return 50.0;
} 
return newBalance * 0.2;
```

Comment: This is best approach though 49.999 isn't handled as before because of the small gap in 
the ranges.

Comment: @DuncG, we don't know if that kind of precision is needed or if the input will already have been rounded to 50.0 but you make a good point so I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Nested `if` statements like below:

```
public static double calculateMinPayment(double newBalance) {
    double x;
    if (newBalance < 0.00) {
        return 0.00;
    } else if (newBalance > 0.00) {
        if (newBalance <= 49.99) {
            x = newBalance;
        } else if (newBalance >= 50.00) {
            if (newBalance <= 300) {
                x = 50.00;
            } else {
                x = newBalance * 0.2;
            }
        } else {
            x = newBalance * 0.2;
        }
    } else {
        x = newBalance * 0.2;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid writing `if` totally, you could do the below. The `LinkedHashMap` keeps track of all conditions and the result to return if the condition is `true`. Since it is a `LinkedHashMap` the order of conditions evaluated is the order in which they are put in the map, similar to the order if you were to write `if` loops.

The logic returns the result of the first condition that evaluates to `true`

Any new condition can be simply added in the `LinkedHashMap`, at the position equivalent to the order in which you want it to be evaluated

```
private static double calculateMinPayment(final double newBalance) {
    LinkedHashMap<Predicate<Double>, Function<Double, Double>> conditionResult = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    conditionResult.put(balance -> balance < 0.0, balance -> 0.0);
    conditionResult.put(balance -> balance < 50.0, balance -> balance);
    conditionResult.put(balance -> balance < 300.0, balance -> 50.0);

    double minPayment = conditionResult.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().test(newBalance))
            .findFirst()
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue().apply(newBalance))
            .orElse(newBalance * 0.2);

    return minPayment;
}
```